# Django CSV Export Choice Display

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a working CSV export function in my Django app.

It exports all fields but doesn't show the verbose or human readable version of the model choice fields.

I am aware of the get_field_display option for templates and views but based on the use of getattr in this function I don't know where to add that bit of code. See code below

```
writer = csv.writer(response)
field_names = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields]

for instance in queryset:

    writer.writerow([unicode(getattr(instance, f)).encode('utf-8') for f in field_names])

return response
```

Where can I inject a bit of code to export the full version of model choices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`model_obj.get_FOO_display()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method

**Example:**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

and the shell response

```
In [2]: foo_obj = Foo.objects.first()

In [3]: foo_obj.get_gender_display()
Out[3]: 'Male'

In [4]: foo_obj.__dict__
Out[4]: 
{'_state': ,
 'id': 1,
 'gender': 'M'}
```

**UPDATE**
use `if...else` statement inside the list comprehension statement.

```
writer.writerow([unicode(getattr(instance, f)).encode('utf-8') if f != 'FOO' else unicode(getattr(instance, 'get_FOO_display')()).encode('utf-8') for f in field_names])
```

**Example**

```
In [8]: class MySample(object):
   ...:     f_name = 'foo'
   ...:     l_name = 'bar'
   ...: 
   ...:     def full_name(self):
   ...:         return self.f_name + " " + self.l_name
   ...:     

In [9]: class_obj = MySample()

In [10]: getattr(class_obj,'f_name')
Out[10]: 'foo'

In [11]: getattr(class_obj,'l_name')
Out[11]: 'bar'

In [12]: getattr(class_obj,'full_name')()
Out[12]: 'foo bar'
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to use the get_field_display() in my bit of code. It uses getattr which is a bit different to a standard queryset. Or at least that's my understanding!

Answer (score 0):

```
    body_rows = []

    for entry in Entry.objects.all():
     row = []


        for key in header_data:

            if key == 'district':
                row.append(entry.get_district_display())
            elif key == 'local_body':
                row.append(entry.get_local_body_display())

            else:
                row.append(getattr(entry, key))

        body_rows.append(row)
```